# `Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'` error in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethereum, blockchain, ethers.js

I am getting the

> Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

error in React. This is the line generating the issue:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers'

const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 33):

Using `any` as a type is cheating. Using “any” will just remove the error but it wont show you the available properties.

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window{
    ethereum?:MetaMaskInpageProvider
  }
}
```

Comment: In MetaMask's doc, it was mentioned that "other Ethereum-compatible browsers" could also have the Window.ethereum. Perhaps putting type `MetaMaskInpageProvider` would make it only compatible for MetaMask?

Comment: @TerryWindwalker as far as I know,  the only browser that  `ethereum` is injected is `Brave` browser which is not a commonly used browser yet

Comment: There is also a library called `@metamask/detect-provider`. Maybe the answer can be updated with this as a possible alternative solution

Answer (score 30):

Create the `react-app-env.d.ts` file in the `src` folder with the following script:

```
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />

interface Window {
    ethereum: any
}
```

Comment: also works for `vite-env.d.ts` 

Comment: Try to avoid using `any`

Answer (score 10):

In my *src/react-app-env.d.ts* I am using

```js
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
import { ExternalProvider } from "@ethersproject/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: ExternalProvider;
  }
}
```

Notice that `@ethersproject/providers` is an `ethers` dependency so you do not need to install it.

Then I also added a *src/hooks/useMetaMask.ts* file with `useMetaMask` hook that casts the provider to MetaMask provider type. This can be useful if you need to add MetaMask listeners.

```js
import type { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

export const useMetaMask = () => {
  const ethereum = global?.window?.ethereum;
  if (!ethereum || !ethereum.isMetaMask) return;
  return ethereum as unknown as MetaMaskInpageProvider;
};
```

Comment: Just wanted to add to this. If you are using Vite, browse over to `src/vite-env.d.ts` and add the following (notice the decorator a the first line):
```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
import { ExternalProvider } from "@ethersproject/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: ExternalProvider;
  }
}
```

Comment: *Note*: You need to have `ethers` installed for this to work!

Answer (score 0):

For my NextJs app, I created a file `web3.d.ts` in the root with the following code:

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from "@metamask/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  }
}
```

Make sure your `tsconfig.json` file allows the above file in `include`.