# Testing metamask - Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'

Tags: typescript, testing, mocha.js, ethers.js

I'm not sure if I understand how testing environment work, because my folder structure is like this:

```
src/
   |index.ts
   |global.d.ts
   |test/
        |myTest.ts
```

global.d.ts contents are below (yea, any is cheating, but nothing is working anyway, so for now let's keep it any). By the way, tests folder is in src because without it visual studio freaks out and can't find the Window interface from global.d.ts file even when i specify typeRoots in tsconfig.ts

```
interface Window {
  ethereum: any
}
```

For mocking metamask in tests I'm using this library: https://github.com/VGLoic/eth-testing

```
describe("wallet detection", () => {

        const testingUtils = generateTestingUtils({ providerType: "MetaMask" });

        it('metamask detection', async () => {
            global.window.ethereum = testingUtils.getProvider();

            const provider = await detectEthereumProvider()

            if (provider != null) {
                console.log("Got metamask")
            } else {
                console.log("No metamask")
            }
        }
    })
```

But I get the error while running mocha tests.

I've tried [`Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'` error in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961190/property-ethereum-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis-error) but it doesn't seem to work because I'm trying to access it in tests folder and not src.
I've even tried moving the tests folder out of src, still same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'\` error in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961190/property-ethereum-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis-error)

Comment: Unfortunately no, because my error occurs in tests. I've spend a couple of days googling but all of the solutions I've found are for /src code and not /test code.
Im thinking of maybe just redoing this with a cypress framework, tho, I've never used it so I'm yet still to find out if it is a good solution for mocking metamask in tests https://javascript.plainenglish.io/setup-typescript-in-cypress-in-4-steps-easily-78a6a8f60860

Comment: why dont you overwrite the type of Window in test file?

Comment: Is it a good practice to do so?