# Metamask | Property MetaMaskEthereumProvider not exist in request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, metamask

before I was using to connect to metamask

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: import("ethers").providers.ExternalProvider;
  }
}
```

and it worked fine with window.ethereum, but it didn't work for the mobile, so I switched to this as instructed:

```
import detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider";

export const requestMetamaskAccount = async (): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();

  if (provider) {
    const accounts = await provider
      ?.request?.({
        method: "wallet_requestPermissions",
        params: [
          {
            eth_accounts: {},
          },
        ],
      })
      .then(() =>
        provider?.request?.({
          method: "eth_requestAccounts",
       })
      );

    return accounts?.[0];
  }
  return undefined;
};
```

Instead now, it giving me this error: Property 'request' does not exist on type 'MetaMaskEthereumProvider'. I thought with detectEthereumProvider, provider was supposed to be equal to window.ethereum in which request should exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`Property 'ethereum' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'\` error in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70961190/property-ethereum-does-not-exist-on-type-window-typeof-globalthis-error)

Comment: I followed this instructions: https://github.com/MetaMask/detect-provider/issues/68

Answer (score 0):

there is no `window.ethereum` on mobile, the reason why it works on desktop is because you have the metamask extension installed already, if not, the same happens. the `window.ethereum` is injected by metamask, to get the equivalent of that, you'll need to run the app in the metamask Dapp browser, `"detectEthereumProvider from "@metamask/detect-provider"` checks to know if you're accessing from a desktop or from a metamask Dapp browser.